# Auto scaling-up Kafka Consumer running from Docker

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka

I have a topic with 10 partitions. I am running my consumer in dockerize environment. I want the docker to auto scale-up/down instances of consumers in the consumer group based on below conditions-

1. Scale up by 1 instance when number of messages being produced on the topic is higher that the number of messages being consumed/processed per time unit.

It should not be auto-scaled if number of consumers in the consumer group is 10 as i am having 10 partitions.

2. Scale down ny 1 instance when number of messages being produced on the  topic is lesser than the number of messages being consumed/processed per time unit.

I am using .net to write my producers/consumers and on-prem Kubernetes for dcokerize the application. Both my producers and consumers are native windows services based on .net core 3.0

Comment: Is your environment Kubernetes, plain Docker, Docker Compose, something else?  If it's Kubernetes, have you researched the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)?

Comment: I am using Kubernetes. Thanks for sharing the doc. I will go through this.I guess I need to use some sort of custom scripts to monitor the lag in the topic per consumer basis and scale-up my application.